# php precision with big numbers

Tags: php, apache2, precision

I have 2 big numbers `1133853003571025.63` and `1732254953579959.21` the sum of these numbers must be `2866107957150984.84`
I'm working with php 5.6 and set the precision parameter to 16, but still php displays an incorrect output.

The output I'm getting is:
number 1: 1133853003571026
number 2: 1732254953579959
Sum : 2866107957150985
number 1 (format): 1133853003571025.75
number 2 (format): 1732254953579959.25
Sum (format): 2866107957150985.00
number length: 16

My code is

```
<?
$num01=1133853003571025.63;
$num02=1732254953579959.21;
$longitud= strlen($num01);
echo "number 1: ".$num01."<br>";
echo "number 2: ".$num02."<br>";
echo "Sum : ".($num01+$num02)."<br>";
echo "number 1 (format): ".number_format($num01, 2, '.', '')."<br>";
echo "number 2 (format): ".number_format($num02, 2, '.', '')."<br>";
echo "Sum (format): ".number_format(($num01+$num02), 2, '.', '')."<br>";
echo "<b>number length: </b>".$longitud."<br>";
?>

My question is what is wrong?, what is missing in my code?
```

Comment: You should probably read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/231316

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP silently converts integer numbers that are too large for PHP to handle (> [`PHP_INT_MAX`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)) to floats. This is by design.

Floating point values in PHP have [limited precision](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php). Take `PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON` into account when doing calculations with floats.

If all this does not suit your needs, take a look at the [bcmath extention](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) for arbitrairy precision. You could use it like this:

```
$a = '1133853003571025.63';
$b = '1732254953579959.21';
print bcadd($a, $b, 2);  // output: '2866107957150984.84'
```

An alternative to using bcmath is to let a database do the calculations, you could pass the calculation in an SQL SELECT statement and retrieve the results. Have a look at [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

MySQL / MariaDB example query:

```
SELECT CAST(1133853003571025.63 + 1732254953579959.21 AS CHAR) AS bignumber;
  -- result: '2866107957150984.84'
```

PostgreSQL example query:

```
SELECT (1133853003571025.63 + 1732254953579959.21)::text AS bignumber;
  -- result: '2866107957150984.84'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried storing the numbers in a database and adding them later. But the numbers are stored incorrectly even using the double precision data type.
Searching the web, I found this page that does the calculation correctly, https: //keisan.casio.com/calculator. I just don't know how it is made and which programming language it works with.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a code example for [bcadd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php) that returns the output that you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help, The php script is fine. The sql statement works fine with mysql but I use postgresql.
`postgres=# SELECT CAST(1133853003571025.63 + 1732254953579959.21 AS CHAR) AS bignumber;
 bignumber 
-----------
 2
(1 row)
`

Comment: `SELECT CAST(1133853003571025.63 + 1732254953579959.21 AS CHAR(19)) AS bignumber;` it works.

Comment: Glad it worked. While PostgreSQL has become my bias after using MySQL for quite a while, many people are still using MySQL / MariaDB. Thanks for adding a PostgreSQL example. I'll add it to the answer.